# Add Content Editor Webpart to Blog-Site

Tags: 2013, my-site, content-editor-web-part, blog

Is it possible to add a `Content Editor Webpart` to a SharePoint 2013 MySite-Blog?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

The default **Edit page** -mode allows you to add web parts to the page. If you wish to do this on a larger scale (not just for individual page on a blog site), you should do this for a copy of the default page layout. Further guidance available e.g. here: http://josharepoint.com/2014/07/14/dealing-with-style-the-sharepoint-2013-blog-template/

Comment: I am not able to change code behind or the masterpage. I have just the ability to add webparts...

Comment: The mentioned Edit page -mode is your choice then. While editing, web parts can be added to available zones just as in any other web part page.